# Joomla redirect index.php to index.php/blog using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, joomla

i am trying to redirect my index.php to index.php/blog using .htaccess..

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+[\s?]
RewriteRule ^$ /index.php/blog [R=301,L]`
```

this code is not working..
Kindly help me on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this rule as **first rule** in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(index\.php)?[\s?]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /index.php/blog/ [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /store/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Dear Anubhava Sir,
Thank you for your valuable feedback.
but the issue didn't resolve.
http://blog.anupammishra.com
its giving me 404 error with URL
http://blog.anupammishra.com/index.php/blog/blog/blog/blog/blog/blog/blog/blog/blog/blog/blog/blog/blog/blog/blog/blog/blog/blog/blog/blog

Comment: I didn't understand your last comment.

Comment: RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /store/$1 [L]
By using this code I find the solution thanks a lot for your cooperation.